# Version of dependencies to Spring Cloud projects in one microservice network

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

Question regarding correct set up of microservice infrastructure with Spring Cloud projects. Let's assume there are service discovery, Gateway, config service and some custom service. All of them have dependecy to Spring Cloud projects of version Camden.
And it is necessary to upgrade one of them (let say Gateway) to version Edware.
Should the rest of microservice also be upgraded to version Edware or can safety stay with Camden?

Comment: It should be fine. The eureka and config server apis are backwards compatible. Though Camden is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at release notes of [Edgware.SR3](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/27/spring-cloud-edgware-sr3-has-been-released), seems like there are couple of fixes in config but thing to notice is `Eureka` is moved to `1.7.2`

Not sure which `Camden` release you are on but supposedly, if you are on `Camden.SR7` and planning to migrate to `Edgware.M1`, there are many releases in between which you have to keep track of and changes that occured in between.

You can find the release dates & sequence [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/releases)

Other than that, there are no more changes so far(atleast not in the release document) that could affect your discussed architecture.

Best bet would be to try and test.